# migration rxjs 5 to 6 issues

Tags: angular, rxjs

i have some code with timer in angular 5

```
    this.timer$ =  
Observable.merge(
    this.timerStart$.mergeMap( () => Observable.interval(1000).takeUntil(this.timerStop$) ).map(() => 1),
    this.timerReset$.map(() => 0)
).scan((acc, n) => n === 0 ? 0 : acc + n )
```

Subscribing to timer$ property i'm getting stream which is controlled by tree other Subjects : timerStart$,  this.timerStop$, timerReset$, just like that

```
this.timerStart$.next(1);
```

After moving to Angular 6 and Rxjs 6 this code is not valid.
I didn't learn deep rxjs before, so translation may take hours. 
Will appreciate much if some rxjs experts could help convert this tricky construction to rxjs 6.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: If you install `rxjs-compat`, you won't have to change anything.

Comment: getting error Observable.merge - merge is not a member of Observable, with rxjs-compat

Answer (score 4):

Your updated code should be as follows:

```ts
     // note merge and interval are imported from rxjs not from rxjs/operators    
    import {merge, interval} from 'rxjs';
    import {mergeMap, map, takeUntil, scan} from 'rxjs/operators';

        this.timer$ =
        merge(
            this.timerStart$.pipe(mergeMap( () => interval(1000).pipe(takeUntil(this.timerStop$)) ), map(() => 1)),
            this.timerReset$.pipe(map(() => 0))
        ).pipe(scan((acc, n) => n === 0 ? 0 : acc + n ))

      // Without subscription, nothing will happen
      this.timer$.subscribe(x =>{});
```

Comment: thank you for help, but not working yet. this structure gives error merge(...).pipe(...), pipe not found for operator function. also timerReset$.map as i understand must be timerReset$.pipe(map(...))

Comment: Yes, should be timerReset$.pipe. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: still error here merge(...).pipe(...) -  pipe not exist for operator function

Comment: Are your imports correct? (import merge from rxjs not from rxjs/operators)

Comment: Without subscription nothing will happen: this.timer$.subscribe(x =>{ })

Comment: just removed comment, because found i tried to console.log from inside pipe but didn't subscribe. Looks like it is working now. I appreciate your help @siva636 so much!